# How can I avoid component render if a value is not ready?

Tags: reactjs, mobx

I'm showing a name on my react class component. This name it is being filled after an API call, if the API responds with none value I'm showing an "ask for the name" title on my component.

Here is my code which works:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  @observable selectedName = ''

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.selectedName = this.props.myName || ''
  }

  async componentDidMount () {
    const id = getLocalStorage('storeId')
    if (id) {
      const { name } = await myContainer.getName({id})

      when(
        () => !isEmpty(name),
        () => this.selectedName = name
      )
    }
  }

  render() {
    const companyName = this.selectedName

    return (
      <div className="my-wrapper">
        {companyName ? companyName
        : (
          <div>ask for the name</div>
        )}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

The issue that I'm having here is that I'm seeing "ask for a name" message when the DOM is ready and after a few milliseconds the DOM change to the name retrieved from the API. How can I avoid this behavior? I tried with a "isLoading" variable, but I'm having the same result, it always loads the "ask for a name" first and the API response later.

Comment: You shouldn't delay render. if not set yet, render this view instead of that view.

Comment: What's your expected behavior? As far as I can see, the app behaves normally. You're using conditional rendering afterall.

Comment: If you don't want it to show anything then replace `<div>ask for the name</div>` with `null`.

Comment: *"The issue that I'm having here is that I'm seeing "ask for a name" message"* - Yes, because that's in the code: `<div>ask for the name</div>`  If you want to display something else, replace that `<div>` with something else.  It could be different text, different markup, `null`, whatever you like.  I don't really see what the problem is here.

Comment: @AbdulrahmanAli it is working but it is showing "ask for a name" for some miliseconds after that it is showing the "name". The behavior that I desire is showing nothing until I have the api response resolved with the name or not.

Comment: @user16967562 what about if the api response an empty string as a "name" value?

Comment: @David I want to display "ask for a name" message when the name is an empty string. If not it should print the "name", but currently my code is showing the "ask for a name" directly without waiting for the response. I want to show "ask for a name" or "name" when the api response finished. Right now it is showing "ask for name" and after some miliseconds it is showing the "name". That is the glitch that I want to avoid, that change on real time.

Comment: @napstercake: That's not a "glitch", it's the code working exactly as designed.  Currently you have two defined states.  Either there's a name or there isn't, and the component displays one thing or the other accordingly.  Perhaps you want to introduce a *third* state?  (1) A name exists in the data.  (2) A name does not exist in the data.  (3) The data is currently being fetched.  If that's the case then you'd introduce logic for a third state.  Perhaps an "isLoading" value which starts as `true` and then gets updated to `false` after the AJAX operation completes.

Comment: @user16967562 after response finished empty string shows "ask for a name", after response finished string with value shows "the name of te company", while response is processing IT SHOULD display nothing.

Comment: What is the value of `id`?

Comment: @user16967562 it is and ID that I save it in the localStorage.

Answer (score 3):

In React components logic take in count that a lot of things are asynchronous, so you need to take that in count in your development logic.
In general, you can show an ActivityLoader or any animation to indicate data are loading.

To make it simple, you could consider this code :

```
  @observable selectedName = ''

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.selectedName = this.props.myName || ''
    this.state = {
        loading: true
    }
  }

  async componentDidMount () {
    const id = getLocalStorage('storeId')
    if (id) {
      const { name } = await myContainer.getName({id})

      when(
        () => !isEmpty(name),
        () => this.selectedName = name
      )
      this.setState({ loading: false })
    }
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.loading) return <div>loading</div>
    else {
      const companyName = this.selectedName
      return (
        <div className="my-wrapper">
          {companyName ? companyName
          : (
            <div>ask for the name</div>
          )}
        </div>
      )
    }
  }
}
```

So loading is set to **true** by default and once your component is loaded you set it to **false**.

Comment: Not Working :( it is only showing the loading message on the div. it never updated

Comment: I took your original code (which is also wrong by the way you are using this.variable) try using state which is also a basic of react development (modified the answer)